# Is it possible to pass dynamic keys to a generic return on a function?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I understand that TypeScript does not exist in runtime. But this should not be necessary in order to achieve my goal.

As an example, let's use the [`Omit<T>` TypeScript utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys):

```js
type MyType = {
  firstKey: string,
  secondKey: string,
  thirdKey: string
}

const x: Omit<MyType, 'secondKey' | 'thirdKey'> = {
  firstKey: 'value'
}
```

This makes me think that it could be possible to write a function that performs this "Omit" operation on existing objects, inferring the correct result type.

```js
const removeKeys = <T extends Record<string, unknown>>(
  data: T,
  fields: Array<keyof T>
): Omit<T, typeof fields[number]> {
  // implementation doesn't matter right now
}
```

The idea is that the function could be used in this way:

```js
const completeObject : MyType = {
  firstKey: 'value1',
  secondKey: 'value2',
  thirdKey: 'value3'
}

const ommitedObject = removeKeys(completeObject, ['secondKey', 'thirdKey'])
// TS could infer the `ommitedType` as Omit<MyType, 'secondKey' | 'thirdKey'>
```

But the signature I just wrote won't work, because `typeof fields[number]` is basically every key from `MyType` since `typeof fields[number]` is interpreted as `typeof keyof T`.

Is there a way to pass the `ommitedKey` argument in `Omit<T, ommitedKey>` dynamically? Not only the `Omit<T, K>`, which could be achieved using the other type [`Exclude<T, U>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludeuniontype-excludedmembers) utility, but any other generic, such as `Pick<T, K>` or a custom generic type.

Comment: @vr partially. I'd expect some way to pass dynamically to any generics, but I see that my question is not very clear. I'll edit the question to make it clearer.

Comment: Dynamic how... all the answers shown essentially achieve the same functionality you are asking for. The only difference is that it is using rest parameters, while you want an array, and in that case, the only thing you need to do is remove `...`.

Comment: It makes no difference. If I were to fix up your code and then implement a similar function for `Pick`, I get [this](https://tsplay.dev/WG2KVm). And now it's clearly the same as the answers posted in the question I linked...